# Using Function Parameter Names in Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift parameter names are used when you call a method, except for the first parameter.  Why is the first name not used?

Using a variation from the Swift manual;

```
var count2: Int = 0
func incrementBy2(amount: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int) {
count2 += amount * times}
```

This will work;

```
incrementBy2(2, numberOfTimes: 7)
```

However this gives me "Extraneous argument label 'amount' in call"

```
incrementBy2(amount: 2, numberOfTimes: 7)
```

Id there a reason for this or is it one of those "just the way it is" things?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is to follow an convention we were all used to from Objective-C, where the name of the first parameter is combined with the method name. Here's an example:

```
- (void)incrementByAmount:(NSInteger)amount
            numberOfTimes:(NSInteger)times
{
    // stuff
}
```

You could call the method like:

```
[self incrementByAmount:2 numberOfTimes:7];
```

And it feels more natural to read by incorporating the name of the parameter into the method's name. In Swift, you can achieve the same with the following:

```
func incrementByAmount(amount: Int, numberOfTimes: Int) {
    // same stuff in Swift
}
```

And call the method like:

```
incrementByAmount(2, numberOfTimes: 7)
```

If you don't want to use this convention, Swift gives you the ability to be more explicit and define separate internal and external parameter names, like so:

```
func incrementByAmount(incrementBy amount: Int, numberOfTimes: Int) {
    // same stuff in Swift
    // access `amount` at this scope.
}
```

You can call the method like this:

```
incrementByAmount(incrementBy: 2, numberOfTimes: 7)
```

Comment: Thank you.  That concept now makes a lot of sense.  Embarrassingly, as simple as it seems I didn't catch it.  :-)

Comment: Note. Now in Swift 2.0 you would call the method `func incrementByAmount(amount amount: Int, numberOfTimes: Int) { }`. Remove the # sign and double up on the parameter name :)

Answer (score 6):

In your example you don't set the name for the first param. You have the variable name only.

Try following please:

```
func incrementBy2(amount am: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int) {
}
```

So you can call it as

`incrementBy2(amount: 0, numberOfTimes: 0)`

and `am` will be the name of the variable inside the function. `amount` will be an external name.

If you want the same external name and variable, you can try this:

```
func incrementBy2(amount amount: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int) {
}
```

And still call like

`incrementBy2(amount: 0, numberOfTimes: 0)`

More info  *Function Parameter Names* and *Specifying External Parameter Names* chapters on Apple's  [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_202)

Comment: Thank you!  I am only on page 21 of the book and looking a little farther ahead makes more sense as to what is going on.  I now understand the use of the # to use the local parameter name.

Comment: Swift has removed the # notation. Now you're supposed to just double up (e.g. `func incrementBy2(amount amount: Int...` )

Answer (score 3):

> Methods in Swift are very similar to their counterparts in
>   Objective-C.  As in Objective-C, the name of a method in Swift
>   typically refers to the  method’s first parameter using a preposition
>   such as with, for, or by,  as seen in the incrementBy method from the
>   preceding Counter class example.  The use of a preposition enables the
>   method to be read as a sentence when  it is called. Swift makes this
>   established method naming convention easy  to write by using a
>   different default approach for method parameters than  it uses for
>   function parameters.
>
> Specifically, Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local  parameter name by default, and gives the second and subsequent
>   parameter  names both local and external parameter names by default.
>   This convention  matches the typical naming and calling convention you
>   will be familiar with  from writing Objective-C methods, and makes for
>   expressive method calls  without the need to qualify your parameter
>   names.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/ru/jEUH0.l

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.  I didn't make it that far in to the book to catch that.

Answer (score 1):

It just uses the same pattern as in objective C, where methods have named parameters except for the first one, which is defined by the method name itself. For example

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can turn the first parameter into a named parameter by explicitly adding a name or by prefixing the parameter name with a hash # character.

By the way, in objective C a method signature is the method name *plus* all named parameters, so for example:

```
- (void) addUser:(User *)user toArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
```

is different than:

```
- (void) addUser:(User *)user toDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict
```

pretty much as in other languages (C#, Java, etc.):

```
void addUser(User user, Array array)
```

is different than:

```
void addUser(User user, Dictionary dict)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't make it that far in to the book to catch that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this answer for the latest version of Swift, the use of `#` to force the usage of a function's first named parameter externally has been removed from the language. In order to specify external parameter names, you now simply separate the external name from the internal name with a space. The `#` was previously used to indicate a parameter with the same name both internally and externally, but now you have to double up the parameter name in the function definition in order to achieve this:

```
var count2: Int = 0
func incrementBy2(amount amount: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int) {
  count2 += amount * times
}
incrementBy2(amount: 2, numberOfTimes: 7) // result is 14
```

You could also differentiate the names for the sake of clarity:

```
var count2: Int = 0
func incrementBy2(theValue amount: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int) {
  count2 += amount * times
  }
incrementBy2(theValue: 2, numberOfTimes: 7)
```

Or just do it the Objective-C way and make it clear what the first parameter should be:

```
var count2: Int = 0
func incrementBy2TheValue(amount: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int) {
  count2 += amount * times
}
incrementBy2TheValue(2, numberOfTimes: 7)
```

I'm not sure how people feel about numerals in function names, however. But I realize this is just an example.

Comment: I liked the `#` ... I wonder what the reason was to remove it