# Swift "with" keyword

Tags: swift

What's the purpose of "with" keyword in Swift? So far I have found that the keyword can be used if you need to override an existing global function, such as toDebugString.

```
    // without "with" you get "Ambiguous use of 'toDebugString'" error
    func toDebugString<T>(with x: T) -> String

    {
        return ""
    }

    toDebugString("t")
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`with` is **not** a keyword - it's just an external parameter identifier. This works as well:

```
func toDebugString<T>(whatever x: T) -> String
```

Since the `toDebugString<T>(x: T)` function is already defined, by using an external parameter you are creating an *overload*: same function name, but different parameters. In this case the parameter is the same, but identified with an external name, and in swift that makes it a method with a different signature, hence an overload.

To prove that, paste this in a playground:

```
func toDebugString<T>(# x: T) -> String {
    return "overload"
}

toDebugString(x: "t") // Prints "overload"
toDebugString("t") // Prints "t"
```

The first calls your overloaded implementation, whereas the second uses the existing function

Suggested reading: [Function Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_254)

Comment: Looks like the parameter names info has been [broken into its own page](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166). Is what you refer to a an "external parameter identifier" the same as an "argument label" -- "_By default, parameters use their parameter name as their argument label_"? Interesting that you can overload a func in Swift with parameter name, not just params and types. Still a little confused; could you have called `toDebugString(#: "t")`? I think that's a yes.

Comment: Things have slightly changed since my answer. Yes, the external parameter identifier is now called argument label, and the `#` character is no longer used — it was used to indicate that the argument label was used for both the internal and external name (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31220235/148357) for an explanation). Your way of calling the function wouldn't work, you have to use the external parameter name `x`, i.e. `toDebugString(x: "t")`