# What does 'on' mean in Swift?

Tags: swift

I know I can use '_' to replace it, but I still don't know what the function of 'on' here, a custom argument label?
[image]

Comment: Essentially the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583477/swift-with-keyword.

Comment: Also: [What are the new “for”, “at”, “in” keywords in Swift3 function declarations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786181/what-are-the-new-for-at-in-keywords-in-swift3-function-declarations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the "external name" for the parameter. So within the function you refer to the argument as `day`, but when calling it, you use the label `on`. It's not a Swift keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

As already explained in the statement you posted.

```
greet(param1 on: param2)
```

`func greet` has two parameters **person and day**:

- 1st parameter you don't have any label that's why **_ is preceded with person** so while calling you simply pass parameter.
- However with 2nd parameter `day` you have label **on** before passing parameter to understand better which can be used while calling function and `day` is a variable which can be used inside func.

Comment: Thank you very much